# Populating the `href` attribute value of a HTML `a` tag in the safest way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to populate the `href` attribute value of a HTML `a` tag in a view file.

```
<a href="<populating_value>">Test name</a>
```

I plan to retrieve that value (the "`<populating_value>`") from a input form text field.

**What is *the safest* process (steps from validation to outputting in the view file) to make that? Where can I find deep information about this matter? What do you advice** (for example: is it safe to populate the `href` attribute value without a previous security check on the string entered by a user?)**?**

*Note*: the value can be an URL or an e-mail address.

Comment: Rails 3 takes care of XSS stuff that would make this functionality vulnerable for you.

Comment: Yeah all strings should be sanitized and any string going into that function should be escaped automatically unless `string.html_safe? = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whats wrong with using `link_to` and escaping the string? If you are unsure of the strings safety call something like `link_to "Test name", h(link)` See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to for more information.

This string should be escaped even without the call to h. Try reading this blog post on the [XSS protection in Rails](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/).